# ReactiveCommand in WPF/ReactiveUI app blocks UI thread

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I am quite a beginner with ReactiveUI and have a strange behavior with a ReactiveCommand.

I want to query data from a database that currently does not support
asynchronous operations. Since we want to exchange the database in the
future with an asynchronous interface I want to write everything as
if the database already would allow async operations. As far as I understand
that would mean that I wrap my database calls at the lowest level in
a Task.

I have a button which is bound to a ReactiveCommand and the command
starts the database query. While the query lasts I want to show some
sort of animation.

The problem is that whatever I tried, the query blocks my UI thread.

Here is part of my code:

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> StartExportCommand { get; }

//The constructor of my view model
public ExportDataViewModel(IDataRepository dr)
{
    this.dr = dr;

    //...

    StartExportCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(() => StartExport());

    //...
}


private async Task StartExport()
{               
    try
    {                
        Status = "Querying data from database...";

        //Interestingly without this call the Status message would not even be shown!
        //The delay seems to give the system the opportunity to at least update the
        //label in the UI that is bound to "Status".
        await Task.Delay(100);

        //### This is the call that blocks the UI thread for several seconds ###
        var result = await dr.GetValues();

        //do something with result...

        Status = "Successfully completed";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Status = "Failed!";

        //do whatever else is necessary
    }
}

//This is the GetValues method of the implementation of the IDataRepository. 
//The dictionary maps measured values to measuring points but that should not matter here.
//ValuesDto is just some container for the values.
public Task<IDictionary<int, ValuesDto>> GetValues()
{            
    //...

    return Task<IDictionary<int, ValuesDto>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //### here is where the blocking calls to the database
        //### specific APIs take place

        return result;
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

}
```

I don't understand why this code is blocking the UI thread although I am wrapping
the long running query in a Task.

Is there something wrong with this pattern or should I go another way with Observables?

**Edit 1**

I am aware of the fact that async != threads. I thought, however, that Task with the TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning would make the blocking code run on a thread pool thread.

**Edit 2**

As recommended by Andy I set a breakpoint inside my task and had a look into the Debug Threads window. It tells me that Task is running on a worker thread. Still my UI is blocking.

Comment: Creating another task within your task could well be unecessary. But you missed out the most interesting part of your code. The part does stuff.  Are the calls to the database really async? Put a break point inside that task and spin it up. Use the Debug>Windows>Threads window to see what thread your code is running on.

Comment: Hmm, the "most interesting" part of the code is a call into a custom ADO.NET provider and this provider is NOT async. That's why I thought I'd have to use a Task in the first place. Would that code really help? Interesting to view the threads debug window: it says within my Task I run on a Worker Thread. Still the UI is blocking.

Comment: I dunno about reactive commands but I would want that command  to be async or using an async action somehow. Then I'd use dapper rather than ado and one of the async extensions. The part of any database call that's expensive is the wait for it to return data and just making everything async from the top down will usually obviate any command blocking.

Comment: I know very little about ADO.NET but could something else further down the line be using the UI thread as a sync context? What happens if you replace your DB calls with a simple Thread.Sleep()?

Comment: There is one speciality here: the original database API can only be compiled as a 32-bit module. To break through the 32/64-bit barrier we wrapped it in a COM library and the ADO.NET provider instantiates that library "out-of-process", i.e. as a standalone COM server. Your comment makes me remember that COM has all sorts of synchronization mechanisms... I will check Thread.Sleep()

Comment: Man, what a great intuition you have! ;-) With Thread.Sleep() everything works as expected (of course without any data). That means it must have to do something with the COM stuff (single threaded apartment synchronization etc..). If you make an answer out of it I'll happily accept it!

Comment: @Andy thanks for mentioning Dapper. If I had known it before, I would have used it instead. Especially since it seems to work well with PostgreSql which will be the database replacement in the future...